# ReactJS MUI5 Globally updating Toolbar height doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, customization

Trying to update globally the `height` property for all the toolbars I use, but it doesn't seem to work. The references I'm using are https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/ and https://mui.com/api/toolbar/. From there I have this:

```
const myTheme = createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiToolbar: {
        root: {
          height: '50px',
          minHeight: '50px',
          maxHeight: '50px'
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Also tried:

```
const myTheme = createTheme({
    components: {
      'MuiToolbar-root': {
          height: '50px',
          minHeight: '50px',
          maxHeight: '50px'
      }
    }
  })
```

Also not working. Both times it continues showing the default theme toolbar. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `styleOverrides` key to change styles injected by MUI into the DOM.
So, something like this should work :

```
const myTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiToolbar: {
      styleOverrides: {
        regular: {
          height: "12px",
          width: "20px",
          height: "32px",
          minHeight: "32px",
          "@media (min-width: 600px)": {
            minHeight: "48px",
          },
          backgroundColor: "#ffff00",
          color: "#000000",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Interesting, the color property works, but the height still doesn't

Comment: `minHeight: "32px !important"` worked too